# Unique comment section per dynamic modal

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a webpage with dynamically loaded cards that pop up into individual modals to display more data. These modals all have their unique id in order to pop up the correct one.

I am attempting to put a unique comment section for each modal. What I have implemented works only for the first modal & doesnt even show the comments on the second modal onwards.

I would appreciate some direction in how to make them display per modal & how to make them unique.  I am assuming I echo $test[id] just like I used for the modals. Need a little assistance in script side of things.

```
 <div id="myModal<?php echo $test['id']; ?>" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
<div class="container">
   <form method="POST" id="comment_form">
   <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $test['id']; ?>">
    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" name="comment_name" id="comment_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <textarea name="comment_content" id="comment_content" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Comment" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="comment_id" value="0" />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
    </div>
   </form>
   <span id="comment_message"></span>
   <br />
   <div id="display_comment<?php echo $test['id']; ?>"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
 var data = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#comment_form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var form_data = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
   url:"add_comment.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:form_data,
   dataType:"JSON",
   success:function(data)
   {
    if(data.error != '')
    {
     $('#comment_form')[0].reset();
     $('#comment_message').html(data.error);
     $('#comment_id').val('0');
     load_comment();
    }
   }
  })
 });

 load_comment();

 function load_comment()
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch_comment.php",
   method:"POST",
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#display_comment').html(data);
   }
  })
 }
 $(document).on('click', '.reply', function(){
  var comment_id = $(this).attr("id");
  $('#comment_id').val(comment_id);
  $('#comment_name').focus();
 });

});
</script>
```

UPDATE:

Going with the response received, I made certain changes & noticed that even though the comment form is visible on all modals, the posted comments itself
only appear on the first modal. With a bit of hardcoding I am able to tell that the display_comment(id) in html & script needs to be same. The HTML id updates as per console, but I am unable to pass the correct id to  $('#display_comment'+myData1).html(data); (it is always 1).

```
<div id="myModal<?php echo $test['id']; ?>" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
<div class="container">
   <form method="POST" id="comment_form">
   <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $test['id']; ?>">
    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" name="comment_name" id="comment_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <textarea name="comment_content" id="comment_content" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Comment" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="comment_id" value="0" />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
    </div>
   </form>
   <span id="comment_message"></span>
   <br />
   <div id="display_comment<?php echo $test['id']; ?>"></div>
  </div>
<div id="dom-target" style="display: none;" data-id="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($test['id']);?>">
    <?php       
    echo htmlspecialchars($test['id']);
    ?>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#comment_form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var form_data = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
   url:"add_comment.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:form_data,
   dataType:"JSON",
   success:function(data)
   {
    if(data.error != '')
    {
     $('#comment_form')[0].reset();
     $('#comment_message').html(data.error);
     $('#comment_id').val('0');
     load_comment();
    }
   }
  })
 });

 load_comment();
 function load_comment()
 {
var myData1 = $("#dom-target").data("id");
console.log('#display_comment'+myData1);
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch_comment.php",
   method:"POST",
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#display_comment'+myData1).html(data);
   }
  })
 }
 $(document).on('click', '.reply', function(){
  var comment_id = $(this).attr("id");
  $('#comment_id').val(comment_id);
  $('#comment_name').focus();
 });
});
</script>
```

I have also tried the following & simply receive undefined as the value in console for myData2:

```
$.ajax({
   url:"fetch_comment.php",
   method:"POST",
   data: {
          myData2: $("#dom-target").data("id")            
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

you should loop all the content according to your $test['id'].
each loop will generate each $test['id'], modals, form.

therefore, you will have multiple form according to each modals.

regarding the name of the input box (name="comment_id","comment_name" etc), just use the same name, as this will affect your backend on how you will process those input ($_POST['']).

this shouldn't be an issue if you area using same input name as user can only submit 1 form on each request.

just the value will be changing based on the form.